# Which Python error message to use for a failed graph traversal and how to handle mypy claiming no return statement for the function?

Tags: python, recursion, types, error-handling, mypy

The try block implicitly returns None if it cannot find a path from start to destination.

Mypy says my function is missing a return statement if I comment out `return None` or it says Incompatible return value type (got "None", expected "List[int]") if I leave it un-commented out.

I want the try block to either only return a List[int] or go to the else block which should raise some sort of error, I am not sure which kind.

```
def dfs_recursive(self, starting_vertex: int, destination_vertex: int, visited_nodes: set=None, initial_path: List[int]=None) -> List[int]:
    """
    Return a list containing a path from
    starting_vertex to destination_vertex in
    depth-first order using recursion.
    """
    try:
        if visited_nodes is None:
            visited_nodes = set()
        if initial_path is None:
            initial_path = []
        visited_nodes.add(starting_vertex)
        next_path = initial_path.copy() # only want to keep branch if it is on the way to destination 
        next_path.append(starting_vertex)
        if starting_vertex == destination_vertex:
            print(next_path)
            return next_path
        else:
            for neighbor in self.get_neighbors(starting_vertex):
                if neighbor not in visited_nodes:
                    neighbor_path = self.dfs_recursive(neighbor, destination_vertex, visited_nodes, next_path)
                    if neighbor_path:
                        return neighbor_path
       # return None 
    except:
        raise KeyError("Oops there is no path")
```

Comment: Why do you have a blanket `except` clause? What exception did you expect to catch?

Comment: I . . . have no idea what I am doing, this is the first exception I've written. Is there a way to write the except only when the return is None?

Comment: `except` catches exceptions. It's not a general "if something goes wrong" handler, because Python has no idea what your idea of "something going wrong" is. You don't seem to be trying to catch an exception, so you shouldn't use `except`.

Comment: If you want to throw an exception when your function reaches the end without returning anything, then just throw an exception at the end of your function.

Comment: Ok, I replaced the commented out return None with an error and mypy is happy. Thank you @user2357112supportsMonica. Question, how come you didn't write an answer? Also, is there a preferred type of error for my error? I couldn't find one that looked correct in the documentation. What about value error? correct type but inappropriate value since the graph has no path from A to B?